# PI Filter After Bridge Rectifier - Inductor at Positive Line or Negative Line

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, bridge-rectifier, emi-filtering

I was reading the [InnoSwitch-CE Family Datasheet](https://ac-dc.power.com/sites/default/files/product-docs/innoswitch3-ce_family_datasheet.pdf) for a design I'm currently working on.

At the **Circuit Board Layout Recommendations** section, it's stated that the inductor should be placed between the negative terminals of the filter capacitors if a pi type (C-L-C) filter is used.

In schematics language, they recommend this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffthhj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

instead of this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmTpbT.png)</sup>

What's the difference? What could be the point? What makes the first arrangement more preferable *(according to the datasheet, at least)*?

Comment: This is for low-power converters. I would balance the inductance between the low- and high-side rails.

Comment: @VerbalKint `I would balance the inductor between the low- and high-side rails.` That's what I've been doing for almost all of my designs. I still can't figure out why they recommend using the 1st arrangement.

Comment: It might be somewhat related to the Y capacitor in fig 10 that regulates the EMI on the output DC terminals.